# Does the order matter in using SqlConnection and SqlCommand

Tags: c#, ado.net

I've seen a lot of code like this

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
{
    con.Open();
    // and so on...
}
```

I am refactoring and it would be very nice to be able to create the command first.  Is there any problem with reversing them, like this?

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1"))     
using (command.Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{        
    command.Connection.Open();
    // and so on...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Several people in the comments wondered why I would do this. I agree that reusing commands in multiple threads is bad. My reason for the inversion is to **refactor the code**.  I have a Web API 2 REST API that reads data from many tables (Audit is one of them) so I have many controller classes. Beneath each controller is a Service class.  So I have AuditService, PersonService, etc.  Add there is a *very high level* of duplicate code in the services.  To reduce that I am moving as much as possible into a CommonService class.

For example,

```
public class AuditService
{
    private readonly CommonService _database;

    public DataTable FindAll()
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Audit"))
        {
            return _database.FindAll(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

and the `CommonService` has this method.

```
public DataTable FindAll(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    using (cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

That seems very clear to me, and easier to unit test.

Comment: That's *not* how commands and connections are used. This refactoring doesn't seem to serve a purpose. The same connection can be used to execute multiple commands. One command can be *reused* with multiple connections. It doesn't have to re-built every time, especially if it takes parameters

Comment: A command can be *reused* with different connections. A meaningful refactoring would be to create the command once and store it in a field. Each time you want to execute it, create a new connection, pass it to the command and execute it. You *don't* need to dispose the command object

Comment: @NewContributor the second snippet uses assignment as an expression in a very .... unconventional way, to set the connection and return it at the same time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ahh, yes I missed that `command.Connection` was the target for `using`.  Maintenance developers will love it

Comment: @NewContributor as I said .... unconventional. The correct expression would break the CoC

Comment: I don't like either one because you're using curly braces for the inner `using` but not the outer one.

Comment: @DanWilson like the vast majority of developers. That's one case where you *don't* really need all those braces. The pattern is commonplace bordering on universal. It's *not* the same case as eg `if` that can easily lead to bugs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - reusing the commands assumes single-threaded use (or per-thread storage for these pre-built commands) or locking which isn't perhaps obvious in a modern multi-threaded world.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't know I was not supposed to use `using` like that.   I can change it to be `using(var con = ...)` and then put `command.Connection = con` inside the block.  Would that be better?

Comment: Just to throw more fuel on the fire, I've always created throw-away command objects with: `using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())` which will instantiate the command object with the connection already assigned.  As others have mentioned, if you're going to reuse the command, this isn't the approach to take.

Comment: The `FindAll()` method as shown is very bad. It will force you to write code that is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Hopefully you have a version that also allows query parameter data. In my own similar designs, I typically don't even provide a string-only option; I want to be **SURE** that using parameters is the default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would not be using the full constructor i.e new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon); then you can declare your SqlCommand before initializing the SqlConnection.
Then you can go ahead to set the sqlCon as a property of the SqlCommand object.
i.e. cmd.Connection = sqlCon;

Just try either ways and see how they work. 
But I advise that you follow best practice (probably for the person who may maintain your code) to always declare and initialize your SqlConnection before that of the SqlCommand.

Comment: It's not best practice to create the connection in advance. It's quite common to create commands once and reuse them with different connections. The problem with the second snippet is that it uses "clever" assignments for no real benefit

Comment: "Clever" code is great and all until your "clever" coworker is on vacation, you are asked to quickly fix a bug in his code, and it takes twice as long to understand what it's doing.

Comment: Quite true. Unless you have a very good reason for doing so. Declare and instantiate your SqlConnection before doing that of the SqlCommand.
That's why I recommend that developers follow good design patterns and best practices.